# Unable to create a model class in Jena Library for Parsing or Extratcting URIS from RDF?XML page

Tags: java, xml, parsing, rdf, jena

I have wriitten following code using the [Jena Library](http://jena.apache.org) to print the URIs on a web page but it is showing a error. The code is

```
      public static void test(String url)
     {
      try
      {
           System.out.println("to go");
           Model read = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(url);
           System.out.println("to go");
           StmtIterator si=read.listStatements();
            System.out.println("to go");
            while(si.hasNext())
             {
             Statement s=si.nextStatement();
               Resource r=s.getSubject();
             Property p=s.getPredicate();
                RDFNode o=s.getObject();
              System.out.println(r.getURI());
               System.out.println(p.getURI());
              System.out.println(o.asResource().getURI());

            }
      }
           catch(JenaException | NoSuchElementException c)
            {    }
          }
```

Can anyone help me further with this problem???

It is not able to create a model read object. The URL is a web address of a xml page.

the following error occurs:

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.<clinit>(Metadata.java:39)
         at com.hp.hpl.jena.JenaRuntime.<clinit>(JenaRuntime.java:37)
         at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.<clinit>(RDFReaderFImpl.java:74)
         at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<clinit>(ModelCom.java:54)
         at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:142)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:136)
at web.crawler.WebCrawler.test(WebCrawler.java:52)
at web.crawler.WebCrawler.main(WebCrawler.java:98)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Comment: What is the error ? c.printStackTrace();

Comment: Is it an ```NoSuchElementException```, that is what I would have assumed?

Comment: I have edited the post along with my errors..

Answer (score 2):

Add all the jars in the lib/ directory of the distribution.  You can use the lib/* form for the classpath.

if you then still get missing org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal (which is in xml-apis), it's because you have an older version of Xerces and old xml-apis.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

the library slf4j*.jar is missing from your classpath.

Comment: thanks pierre.It worked but now it required Apache.Xerces lib.I added that to. Again it is asking for org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal library. Am i on right track and is there any other libraries required ..

Comment: hey.it worked after adding six other libraries it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @PrannoyMittal, here on SO, you are required to both upvote and accept an answer when it solves your problem (and also upvote other useful answers)

Comment: hey...still i am not authorized to vote up..have't got 15 reputations.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the libraries I had to add more:

```
  import org.slf4j.*;
  import org.apache.xerces.util.XMLChar;
  import org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal;
  import org.apache.jena.iri.IRIFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding all the libraries availables at jena lib dir. 
I gess Jena need another lib or jar file, but I dont know the especific .jar, so I add all of them.
Then it works!